# Process.Start impersonation with ServiceUser credentials / run code in the context of a ServiceUser (without login permissions to the machine)

Tags: c#, service, impersonation, process.start

We are having several departments with individual Service-Accounts on a Windows Domain (Active Directory) and want to use them to impersonate a console command to run it with Process.Start and set the username and password in the code. Process.Start requires a ProcessInfo class object, where a domain, username and password can be provided.

The commands need to be run under these Service-Account credentials to access related network-shares and manipule their structure and files with a cli-program.

The problem is, that all tries so far with running Process.Start within a webservice or api on a IIS server, we still got into the same problem: It seems to be required, that ProcessInfo can only use the other credentials, if the particular user is having login permissions on the running machine.
All the service users are not having rights to directly login to the machine, so the command cannot be run and an Exception is throwing.

**Exception message:**
Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer

**Workaround:**
To properly run these commands, we are thinking about creating multiple instances of the webservice/api and impersonate it via the IIS AppPool and assign the relevant service user. Each instance will then have a specific service run in which context IIS is serving the webservice/api.

Our goal is to accomplish the webservice/api in a single instance and change user credentials dynamically grabbed from database (username/password).

**Is this possible in any way?**

Like ServiceUsers can be assigned to windows service (machine/server), which are not needing login permissions.

I just want to ask, before we going the way of the workaround and creating several instances for this solution... Any helping comments or different ideas of solving this challenge are welcome. Thank you, folkz.

Answer (score 0):

The missing logon type may well be "Log on as a batch job" - see if granting the service accounts this right helps.

The exact steps to achieve this might vary between different versions of Windows but will be something like this;

1. Start the "Local Security Policy" app (AKA secpol) Go to Security
2. Go to Settings | Local Policies | User Rights Assignment
3. Edit "Log on as a batch job" and add your service account

If this does not work then don't forget to undo the above - don't leave experimental security changes lying around!

Comment: For Process.Start it is (imho) not possible to specify a logon type, while not offering a member for this option ... 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.6.1

Do you talk about impersonation?

Comment: @SiL3NC3 permitted logon types are part of local security policy, not something you can specify at Process.Start - I've updated my answer with the steps you can try.